# URL after Location Hash not being detected by the Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am setting up an extension that prefills a Google form and adds the current URL into one of the fields in the form. However, the issue is that the extension isn't able to detect the complete URL. It only detects www.xyz.com/home.html while the complete URL includes a location hash(www.xyz.com/home.html#e12345678) which is very important and will need to be added to the form. Any ideas on how I can set this up?

I use the following code:

`var url = tabs[0].url;
var furl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/xyz/viewform?entry.123="+url;
    window.open(furl);`

Comment: Sounds like your code is running at the wrong time. Can't really help without seeing more code.

Comment: Hi wOxxOm, the code is running fine. The only issue is that the location hash isn't being picked up by the chrome extension. It just picked up everything until the #. Wanted to know if there is a way to get that info as well.

Comment: Also, this is my first extension and these are basically, the main lines of code. Let me know what code you'd like to see and I'll try including a sample.

Comment: Try encoding all special symbols: `var url = encodeURIComponent(tabs[0].url);`

Comment: Also make sure to learn debugging in devtools so you can step through the code line by line and inspect how your variables are being assigned and transformed.

Comment: Hey WoZZOm, That code works perfectly. Thank you very much. I understand. I will look into how to troubleshoot using the Dev tools.